# Not able to detect flash button pressed on Nodemcu

Tags: iot, esp8266, micropython

I am working with simple Micropython with Esp8266 module and not able to detect if flash button on esp is pressed

I tried using pin 0 but it is not working.

```py
p2=Pin(0,Pin.IN)
while True:
    print(p2.value())
    if p2.value():
        break;
```

I also tried this but it is also not working as expected.

```py
p2 = Pin(0,Pin.PULL_DOWN)
while True:
    print(p2.value())
if p2.value():
        break;
```

Comment: You should configure it as an pullup and check for a situation where it reads low or false.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my problem.
here it is how i able to detect flash button on esp

```
flash_btn = Pin(0, Pin.IN, Pin.PULL_UP)
```

Comment: Please make the code in your self answer at least as complete as the non-working code in your question, ie, include not only the configuration but the detection as well.